# Grouping and ungrouping a specified range with excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

i have a range of cells (A60 TO Y70) . I would like to group and ungroup the columns of these cells as they are way too broad and thus complexed to view. Is it possible to ungroup and group a specified range with the use of VBA. There are many more ranges of such thus this function would be really useful for me! Thank you:)

Comment: Basically, you can group a part of the range like  `set ColAtoD = Range("A60:D70")`, then ColAtoD is the range from column A to D. Then you can select a specific column later like `ColAtoD.Columns(3).Select` if you want to select the third column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the group function:

```
Range("a60", "y70").Group
```

or ungroup them:

```
Range("a60", "y70").Ungroup
```

Comment: Is it possible to do a user input to group and ungroup ?Becase i have manay ranges of such thus hardcoding would be a hassle, especially when the ranges change

Comment: Yest you can... you can do it with an inputbox or with a selected range the user selected perior to the macro.